# Why does my application occupy and not release memory?

Tags: java, h2

Below is my test code. H2 database. In the example, at startup, the first 15 seconds of RAM consumption is 11 MB. Next comes the creation of a table and repeated access to the database to write data. At this point, the consumption of RAM increases. After the cycle with calls is completed, there is no connection to the database, but the RAM is still busy. Why is that? Shouldn't the memory be freed? And how to achieve this? And in general, what is this occupied volume? If you increase the number of repetitions of the loop, the occupied memory will no longer be, or it will become slightly larger.

I tried to change the fields of the created table. Tried to forcefully close the connection to the database. I expected that the DBMS, after accessing it, would not take up space in RAM

[image]

[image]

````
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class H2CreateExample {
    
    private static String jdbcURL = "jdbc:h2:~/biba";
    private static String jdbcUsername = "sa";
    private static String jdbcPassword = "";

    private static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }

    private static void printSQLException(SQLException ex) {
        for(Throwable e: ex) {
            if(e instanceof SQLException) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                System.err.println("SQLState: " + ((SQLException) e).getSQLState());
                System.err.println("Error Code: " + ((SQLException) e).getErrorCode());
                System.err.println("Message: " + e.getMessage());
                Throwable t = ex.getCause();
                while (t != null) {
                    System.out.println("Cause: " + t);
                    t = t.getCause();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static final String createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE `data` (\n"
            + " `id` BIGINT auto_increment,\n"
            + " `date` DATE NOT NULL,\n"
            + " `dataText` TEXT,\n"
            + " `dataImage` JAVA_OBJECT,\n"
            + " PRIMARY KEY (`id`)"
            + ");";
    
    private static void createDataTable() throws SQLException {
        try (Connection connection = getConnection(); Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
            statement.execute(createTableSQL);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            printSQLException(e);
        }
    }
    
    private static final String INSERT_USERS_SQL = "INSERT INTO `data`" +
            " (`date`, `dataText`, `dataImage`) VALUES " +
            " (?, ?, ?);"; //ПОПРАВИТЬ ЗАПРОС
    
    public static long add(Date date,
            String dataText,
            ImageIcon image) throws SQLException {
        
        long result = -1;
        
        try (Connection connection = getConnection();
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_USERS_SQL)) {
            preparedStatement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
            preparedStatement.setString(2, dataText);
            preparedStatement.setObject(3, image);
            
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            printSQLException(e);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        
        createDataTable();
        System.out.println("Таблица создана");
        
        File file = new File("/home/drevnicky/Images/black.jpg");
        ImageIcon image = null;
        
        try {
            image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(file));
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        
        for(int k = 0; k<50; k++) {
            add(new Date(), "Text 123", image);
            System.out.println("k " + k);
        }
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        
    }
}```
````

Comment: Depending on the garbage collector Java uses (either automatically configured, or explicitly by you), and its configuration, the Java process might not release memory back to the OS once allocated.

Comment: Furthermore, if H2 runs in-memory, then all data related to the H2 database is kept in-memory. This data can obviously not be deleted and can only be removed when the application stops (and tears down the in-memory H2 database as well).

Comment: please try these: `System.gc();` and `System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());` (before/after gc)

Comment: The value 110184176 is displayed before System.gc() is executed, and 9480752 is displayed afterwards. In Task Manager, the maximum value of occupied RAM is 250 MB. This is much smaller than in the photo attached to the question. It turns out that the garbage collector partially helps to solve the problem